# Safari iOS 7.1 minimal-ui and Smart App Banner

Tags: safari, safari-minimal-ui

I seem to have an issue with iOS 7.1's `minimal-ui` feature when used in conjunction with the smart app banner.

I have a gap at the top of the page, with the app banner overlaying the page content.

I've turned all styles off in my page, so I know its not my own CSS causing this.

Is this an iOS bug?

**Edit:** Demo: [demo](http://blog.muonlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ios.html)

and a screenshot:

[image: Gap above page]

Comment: The size of the bar looks to be the same size as the status bar, do you have code to try to offset your page by the status bar height?

Comment: See the demo link: http://blog.muonlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ios.html You can cause it with zero content/scripts/css. iOS bug methinks. sigghhhh

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a bit of javascript here is how I fixed it.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, minimal-ui" />
<script>
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.write('<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=XXXXXXXX"/>');
</script>
```

This basically forces a scroll before telling Safari to use the banner.

Comment: This didn't work for me, in that the document.write didn't cause the smart banner to show up at all (iOS 7.1.1). We ended up just removing `minimal-ui`, as it wasn't absolutely essential.

Answer (score 0):

The `minimal-ui` viewport property is **no longer supported** in iOS 8 (see [iOS 8 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/)).

Therefore, my recommendation is to **not use `minimal-ui`** at all and the smart banner will display just fine.